# screen resolution changing the CSS

Tags: css, cross-browser

I'm not very experienced in cross-browser issues, but I'm having this issue:

**Scenerio :**  Let say i have `div` of `width:800px`, in that `div` i have 2 buttons ( left-araow--right-arrow ), `onclick` on any of the button I change image position in the `div` ( image move right or left,but stays in outer `div` )

**Problem :** When I re-size or reduce screen resolution then my CSS gets change; the image goes out of the div, and also the position of my buttons get change as well.

Any idea or solutions? Thanks.

**EDIT :** It is working fine in Firefox and in Opera, but not working in Google Chrome and  IE.

Below is the html:

```
<div class="hand">
    <div id="handinside"></div> 
</div>
<div id="left" class="button"> left </div> 
<div class="flip"></div>
<div id="right" class="button">right</div>
</div>
```

below is the CSS

```
.gameNavigation {
    width: 220px;
    margin: 0px auto 0px;
}

.button {
    margin: 0 0 0 5px; 
    cursor: pointer; 
    width: 59px; 
    height: 29px; 
    float: left; 
    text-align: center; 
    background-color:red;
    color: white;
}


.hand {
    position:relative;
    background-color:transparent;
    left:0px;
    width:140px;
    height:210px;
}
```

Below is the jquery

```
    $(".button").click(function() {
    var $button = $(this);
    var oldValue = $("#counter").val();
    if ($button.text() == "right"  )  {
        //move right if the value is no more than 4
        if(parseInt(oldValue) < 3){
            var newVal = parseInt(oldValue) + 1;
            $(".hand").animate({
                "left": "+=222px"
            }, "slow");
            $(".coin").animate({
                "left": "+=222px"
            }, "slow");
        //$(".block").stop();
        }
    }
    else {
        // move left and don't allow the value below zero
        var test = 'test'
        if (oldValue >= 1) {
            var newVal = parseInt(oldValue) - 1;
        }

        if(parseInt(newVal) >= -1){
            $(".hand").animate({
                "left": "-=222px",
                easing :'swing'
            }, "slow");
            $(".coin").animate({
                "left": "-=222px",
                easing : 'swing'
            }, "slow");
        }

    }
    $("#counter").val(newVal);
});
```

Comment: Please provide your code in jsfiddle.net ..

Comment: Post your code here, that will help us understand your problem.

Comment: Sounds like you need to use percentages to position your items instead of pixels...I think, can't really tell what your on about.

Comment: i have added my code, kindly have a look

Comment: @user1409822 you've got too many closing div tags in your html, the last one is extraneous

Answer (score 0):

position your container div with relative positioning and then position your arrows with absolute positioning

Comment: i have modified my jquery where i am giving left margin in pixels, now i have done it with % and its working in google chrome and in all other browsers aswell, problem left with F*** INTERNET EXPLORER :-(